# How can I detect whether a type is list-initializable?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, narrowing

Background: I'm writing a wrapper type like `Either<A, B>`, and I'd like `return {some, args};` to work from a function returning `Either<A, B>` exactly when it'd work from a function returning `A` or `B`. However, I also want to detect when ***both*** `A` and `B` could be initialized with `{some, args}`, and produce an error to protect users from the ambiguity.

To detect whether a type `T` can be initialized from some arguments, I tried writing a function like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});

// imagine some other fallback overload here...
```

I thought the expression `testInit<T>(some, args)` should be valid exactly when `T{some, args}` is valid — in the code below, the initialization `auto x = MyType{1UL, 'a'};` works, and this test also passes:

```
struct MyType {
    MyType(size_t a, char b) {}
};
auto x = MyType{1UL, 'a'};  // ok
static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(testInit<MyType>(1UL, 'a'))>::value, "");  // ok
```

However, when we add a constructor from `std::initializer_list<char>`, it breaks:

```
struct MyType {
    MyType(size_t a, char b) {}
    MyType(std::initializer_list<char> x) {}  // new!
};
auto x = MyType{1UL, 'a'};  // still ok

// FAILS:
static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(testInit<MyType>(1UL, 'a'))>::value, "");
```

> `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = MyType, Args = <unsigned long, char>]: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'unsigned long' to 'char' in initializer list`
>
> ```
> auto testInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
>      ^                                      ~~~
> ```

Why is Clang refusing to resolve my `(size_t, char)` constructor in favor of the `initializer_list` constructor? **How can I correctly detect whether `return {some, args};` would work in a function returning `T`**, regardless of whether it's an aggregate type, a user-defined constructor, or an `initializer_list` constructor?

Answer (score 3):

It's a little complicated.

And I'm not really an expert so I can say something non completely exact: take what I say with a pinch of salt.

First of all: when you write

```
auto x = MyType{1UL, 'a'};  // ok
```

the constructor called is the initializer list one, not the one that receive a `std::size_t` and the `char`.

And this works because the first value, `1UL` is an `unsigned long int` but with a value (attention: a **value**) that can be narrowed to `char`. That is: works because `1UL` is a value that fits in a `char`.

If you try

```
auto y = MyType{1000UL, 'a'};  // ERROR!
```

you get an error because `1000UL` can't be narrowed to a `char`. That is: the `1000UL` doesn't fit in a `char`.

This works also with `decltype()`:

```
decltype( char{1UL} )    ch1; // compile
decltype( char{1000UL} ) ch2; // ERROR
```

But consider this function

```
auto test (std::size_t s)
   -> decltype( char{s} );
```

This function gives immediately a compilation error.

You can think: "but if a pass `1UL` to `test()`, `decltype()` can narrow the `std::size_t` value to a `char`"

The problem is that C and C++ are strongly typed languages; if you permit that `test()`, works, returning a type, when receive some values of `std::size_t`, you can create (via SFINAE) a function that return a type for some values and another type with another types. This in unacceptable from the point of view of a strongly typed language.

So

```
auto test (std::size_t s)
   -> decltype( char{s} );
```

is acceptable only if `decltype( char{s} )` is acceptable for all possible values of `s`. That is: `test()` is unacceptable because `std::size_t` can hold the `1000UL` that doesn't fit in a `char`.

A little change now: make `test()` a template function

```
template <typename T>
auto test (T s)
   -> decltype( char{s} );
```

Now `test()` compile; because there are types `T` with all values that can be narrowed to a `char` (`T = char`, by example). So `test()`, templatized, isn't intrinsically wrong.

But when you use it with a `std::size_t`

```
decltype( test(1UL) ) ch;  // ERROR
```

you get an error because `test()` can't accept a `std::size_t`. Neither a value that can be narrowed to a `char`.

This is exactly the problem of your code.

Your `testInit()`

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit(Args&&... args)
   -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
```

is acceptable because there are types `T` and `Args...` so that `T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}` is acceptable (example: `T = int` and `Args... = int`).

But `T = MyType` and `Args... = std::size_t, char` is unacceptable because the constructor used is the one with an initializer list of `char` and non all `std::size_t` values can be narrowed to a `char`.

Concluding: you get an error compiling `decltype(testInit<MyType>(1UL, 'a')` because you get an error compiling `MyType{1000UL, 'a'}`.

Bonus answer: I suggest an improvement (IMHO) for your `testInit()`.

Using SFINAE and the power of the comma operator, you can write

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit (Args ... args)
   -> decltype( T{ args... }, std::true_type{} );

template <typename...>
std::false_type testInit (...);
```

So you can write some `static_assert()` simply as follows

```
static_assert( true == decltype(testInit<MyType>('a', 'b'))::value, "!"); 
static_assert( false == decltype(testInit<MyType>(1UL, 'b'))::value, "!");
```

Post scriptum: if you want that the `MyType(size_t a, char b) {}` constructor is called, you can use the round parentheses

```
auto y = MyType(1000UL, 'a');  // compile!
```

So if you write `testInit()` with round parentheses

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit (Args ... args)
   -> decltype( T( args... ), std::true_type{} );

template <typename...>
std::false_type testInit (...);
```

you pass both following `static_assert()`s

```
static_assert( true == decltype(testInit<MyType>('a', 'b'))::value, "!"); 
static_assert( true == decltype(testInit<MyType>(1UL, 'b'))::value, "!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. This is a great explanation of the current behavior. What I'm still missing is an answer to my original goal: _"How can I correctly detect whether `return {some, args};` would work in a function returning `T`?_"

Comment: @jtbandes - the answer was "your `testInit()` works correctly". `return {some, args};` should give error if `some` is a `std::size_t` and you're returning a `MyType`; different if you want call the `std::size_t`/`char` constructor: you have to `return T(some, args);` (and modify `testInit()` consequently)

Answer (score 1):

I think that [@max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47352765/27678) thoroughly answered what was happening here; initializer_list constructors are greedy so we must be wary.

To answer your second question:

> How can I correctly detect whether `return {some, args};` would work in a function returning `T`, regardless of whether it's an aggregate type, a user-defined constructor, or an initializer_list constructor?

[`std::is_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) is *usually* the way to go here, however it only checks that parenthetical construction works, so in your case, the following `static_assert` fails:

```
static_assert(std::is_constructible<MyType, char, char, char>::value, "");
```

Additionally, even if it *did* work, there'd be no way to tell if we needed to use curly braces or regular parentheses to perform the initialization.

So, let's alias `is_constructible` to be a more specific `is_paren_constructible`:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
using is_paren_constructible = std::is_constructible<T, Args...>;

template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr bool is_paren_constructible_v = 
    is_paren_constructible<T, Args...>::value;
```

Note that I will be using C++14 and C++17 features in this answer, but we can accomplish the same things with just C++11.

Now let's also distinguish between list-initialization with another trait, `is_list_constructible`. To do this, I will make use of the voider-pattern (`std::void_t` was introduced in C++17 to aid this, but I defined it myself to be more C++11 like):

```
struct voider{
  using type = void;
};

template<class... T>
using void_t = typename voider<T...>::type;

template<class T, class Args, class=void>
struct is_list_constructible : std::false_type{};

template<class T, class... Args>
struct is_list_constructible<T, std::tuple<Args...>,  
  void_t<
      decltype(T{std::declval<Args>()...})
        >
>: std::true_type{};

template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr bool is_list_constructible_v = 
    is_list_constructible<T, std::tuple<Args...>>::value;
```

This makes things a little weird for your `testInit` function. Should we use parenthetical construction or list-initialization? We could always split it into two...

```
template<class T, class... Args>
auto listInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(listInit<MyType>('0', 'a'))>::value, "");

template<class T, class... Args>
auto parenInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(parenInit<MyType>(1UL, 'a'))>::value, "");
```

But that's no fun, we'd rather have a single entry point that would "just do the right thing", so let's make a new function, `do_init` that will first attempt list-initialization (at compile-time), and failing that, will attempt parenthetical initialization:

```
template<class... Args>
MyType do_init(Args&&... args)
{
    constexpr bool can_list_init = is_list_constructible_v<MyType, Args...>;
    constexpr bool can_paren_init = is_paren_constructible_v<MyType, Args...>;
    static_assert(can_list_init || can_paren_init, "Cannot initialize MyType with the provided arguments");

    if constexpr(can_list_init)
        return MyType{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    else
        return MyType(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

in `main` we can call our `do_init` function and it will construct `MyType` in the appropriate fashion (or fail a static_assert otherwise):

```
int main(){
    (void)do_init('a', 'b'); // list init
    (void)do_init(10000UL, 'c'); // parenthetical
    (void)do_init(1UL, 'd'); // parenthetical
    (void)do_init(true, false, true, false); // list init

    // fails static assert
    //(void)do_init("alpha");
}
```

We could even combine `is_list_constructible` and `is_paren_constructible` into a single trait, `is_constructible_somehow`:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
constexpr bool is_constructible_somehow = std::disjunction_v<is_list_constructible<T, std::tuple<Args...>>, is_paren_constructible<T, Args...>>;
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(is_constructible_somehow<MyType, size_t, char>, "");
static_assert(is_constructible_somehow<MyType, char, char, char>, "");
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2yPQmELpBRIjG6LP)

Answer (score 0):

There is some strange behavior if a constructor exists with `std::initializer_list` if you init your object with `{}`.

Example:

```
struct MyType 
{
    MyType(size_t , char ) { std::cout << "Construct via size_t/char" << std::endl;}
    MyType(std::initializer_list<char> ) { std::cout << "Construct via list" << std::endl;}
};

auto x1 = MyType{1UL, 'a'};   
auto x2 = MyType((1UL), 'b');
```

For x1 it runs into the initializer llist constructor because you are using the `{}` syntax. If you use the `()` syntax, you get the *expected* constructor called. But you run into the most vexing parse problem, so additional braces are needed!

Back to your code, in your test function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
```

you are using `{}`. If you change to `()` everything works fine!

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
auto testInit(Args&&... args) -> decltype(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

why:

> §13.3.1.7 [over.match.list]/p1:
>
> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and `T` has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization,
>   if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, the initialization is
>   ill-formed.

In addition, initializer list constructors do not allow narrowing!

> §8.5.4 List-initialization
>
> (3.4) Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable
>   constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload
>   resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion
>   (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the 
>   program is ill-formed.

In your case, your test function catches the initializer list constructor as it is preferred if it is available and and list initialization is used. Simply that ends in the narrowing failure.

Comment: Now it fails on `static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(testInit<MyType>('a', 'b', 'c'))>::value, "");`

Comment: @AndyG: Because it is not a initializer_list nor mathcing any other constructors. If you use `static_assert(std::is_same<MyType, decltype(testInit<MyType>(std::initializer_list<char>{'a', 'b', 'c'}))>::value, "");` everything is fine. Before the test function do a conversion to initializer list which is not a good idea for a test function I believe.